# line.new crosses over label.new (now to resolve)

Tags: pine-script

Afternoon all,

I am trying to create a label and line. Label shows daily open including value and then line from there to the price axis.

But the line.new partially covers the information within the label. I think the issue is that I am using bar_index(within line.new), but I can't seem to work out what I would use instead so that the line.new start after the label.new.

Thank you for your time.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Label Testing", overlay=true)

dOpen = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

var line dOpenLine = na
if PriceLine 
    dOpenLine := line.new(bar_index[1], dOpen, bar_index, dOpen, color=color.blue, style=line.style_dashed, width=2, extend=extend.right)
    label dOpenLabel = label.new(bar_index, dOpen, text = "dOpen -   "+tostring(dOpen), color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_left, size=size.small )
    
    line.delete(dOpenLine[1])
    label.delete(dOpenLabel[1])
```

#####Update 18/03/2021#######

line.new will take precedence over `label.new` and will cover the text within label.new.

Slight hack is to add `\n` within the text this will then place a return carriage placing the text above the line and price below the line within the label.

```
label dOpenLabel = label.new(bar_index, dOpen, text = "dOpen\n\n"+tostring(dOpen), color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_left, size=size.small, xloc=xloc.bar_index )
```

Or if you have OCD and want text above the line.new but then you can't have a `label.new` box or `style = label.style_label_left`.

```
label mOpenLabel = label.new(bar_index, mOpen, text = "mOpen - "+tostring(mOpen), color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.yellow, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
```

Final question I am trying to workout is how to position the text. I would like to position the text to stick to the price axis (shown in the below picture).

[image]

Currently I am trying to move the text with spaces as shown below code.

```
 label mOpenLabel = label.new(bar_index, mOpen, text = "                                                                                                                                                    mOpen - "+tostring(mOpen), color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.yellow, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal,  xloc=xloc.bar_index)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let your label point to the right, so it doesn't intersect.

```
//@version=4
study("Label Testing", "LBL", overlay=true)

var bool    PriceLine   = true

var line    dOpenLine   = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.blue, style=line.style_dashed, width=2, extend=extend.right)
var label   dOpenLabel  = label.new(na, na, text = "", color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_right, size=size.normal)

dOpen = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

if PriceLine 
    line.set_xy1(dOpenLine,    bar_index[1], dOpen)
    line.set_xy2(dOpenLine,    bar_index,    dOpen)
    label.set_xy(dOpenLabel,   bar_index,    dOpen)
    label.set_text(dOpenLabel, "dOpen -   " + tostring(dOpen))
```

[image: Label points right]

Comment: I was after the label not covering the current price action. 
I see that bar_index[1] moves the line.new to the left (for example bar_index[100]) but it is not possible use a minus number.
If there is no way for label.new to be in front of line.new is there a way of off centering the text within the label maybe?

Comment: Adding \n\n kinda works.     label dOpenLabel = label.new(bar_index, dOpen, text = "dOpen\n\n"+tostring(dOpen), color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_left, size=size.small,  xloc=xloc.bar_index )
But

Comment: Bjorn have gone for "style=label.style_none" as this places the text above the line. 
How would place the text all the way to the right. Right next to the price axis?

Comment: To answer on one of your previous comments, `label.new()` has a parameter `textalign=` which allows to alignment of the label text. As for putting the text right next to the price action, I'm not sure this can be done. At least, I don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: I am new to label.new and am use to using plot(). When using plot() I would use offset.

How would I offset (or move the text further to the right from "bar_index" without putting in loads of spaces?

Comment: You can't add text to a `plot()`. And `offset=` just moves your plot. Not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Bjorn, I have updated my question 1. for users that might have a similar question in the future and 2. to try explain the text alignment. Your assistance will be gratefully received.

Comment: I don't think that what you're asking for can be done. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309871/horizontal-ray-effect-in-pinescript-label-to-right-hand-side-price-axis

Comment: Cheers Bjorn. I have marked as answered as it answers my question that it can't be achieved. Thank you for your time.