# Label positioning and/or alignment

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to add some lines to my charts to illustrate the opening price on different timeframes.

What I've gotten to work so far is drawing lines in correct location on the price (Y) axis, either by using `bar_time` or `bar_index`, but this doesn't plot the lines beside the bars on the time (X) axis of any other timeframes except the timeframe I'm currently viewing.  I suppose to solve that, maybe what I need to do is find `time` for the `open` of each timeframe and use that as `x` (`label.new`) and `x1` (`line.new`)?  Any pointers on how I can go about that?

In addition, I would like to plot labels just above each of these lines.  I'd like to keep the labels out of the way of the bars so they don't overlap them and clutter the view.  Ideally I'd like them to stay against the right side of the X axis of the chart, against the scale, but I can't seem to make that work either.  In either case, they just sit on top of the bar.  I've noticed that if I only use text, I have a bit more control, but as soon as I do `"text " + variable` like in my example below, any little control I had is totally gone.

What I've been wrestling with all day has lead me to this sample snippet and I'd love some pointers to try to help clear the log jamb?

```
//@version=4
study(title="FTC Levels", shorttitle="FTC Levels", overlay=true)

dOpen = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open)
wOpen = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', open)
mOpen = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', open)
qOpen = security(syminfo.tickerid, '3M', open)
yOpen = security(syminfo.tickerid, '12M', open)

if barstate.islast
    line.new(time, dOpen, time + 1, dOpen, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow, style=line.style_dotted)
    label.new(bar_index, dOpen, "Daily Open: " + tostring(dOpen), textcolor=color.yellow, style=label.style_none)

    line.new(time, wOpen, time + 1, wOpen, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow, style=line.style_dotted)
    label.new(bar_index, wOpen, "Weekly Open: " + tostring(wOpen), textcolor=color.yellow, style=label.style_none)

    label.new(bar_index, mOpen, "Monthly Open: " + tostring(mOpen), textcolor=color.yellow, style=label.style_none)
    line.new(time, mOpen, time + 1, mOpen, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow, style=line.style_dotted)

    label.new(bar_index, qOpen, "Quarterly Open: " + tostring(qOpen), textcolor=color.yellow, style=label.style_none)
    line.new(time, qOpen, time + 1, qOpen, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow, style=line.style_dotted)

    label.new(bar_index, yOpen, "Yearly Open: " + tostring(yOpen), textcolor=color.yellow, style=label.style_none)
    line.new(time, yOpen, time + 1, yOpen, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow, style=line.style_dotted)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you could manually draw on the chart what you would like it to look like so I can get a visual understanding and add the picture to your question.

Comment: Reference the text to the right. I have previously asked this question and it is not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66675006/line-new-crosses-over-label-new-now-to-resolve